# How to extract a specific input field value from external webpage using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i get the webpage content from an external website using ajax but now i want a function which extract a specific input field value which is already autofilled.

the webpage content is like this:

```
.........
<input name="fullname" id="fullname" size="20" value="David Smith" type="text">
<input name="age" id="age" size="2" value="32" type="text">
<input name="income" id="income" size="20" value="22000$" type="text">
.........
```

I only want to get the value of `fullname`, maybe with some javascript regex, or some jQuery dom parser, i know i can do it easily with php but i want it using Javascript or jQuery.

Note: this inputs are not hosted in my page, they are just pulled from other website through Ajax.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery `find` method like `$(response).find('#fullname').val()`. Refer [jQuery find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) Documentation here

Answer (score 1):

jQuery to the rescue:

```
var body = '<div><input name="fullname" id="fullname" size="20" value="David Smith" type="text"><input name="age" id="age" size="2" value="32" type="text"><input name="income" id="income" size="20" value="22000$" type="text"></div>';
var selector = 'input[name=fullname]';
alert($(selector, body).val());
```

EDIT: [Example at jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/anaze3/edit).